# Reset VS2010 Project Templates?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I installed Blend 4 RC recently but strangely it deleted some of my VS2010 projects templates, including the most important ones being Silverlight User Control and Silverlight Application.

Does anybody know how to get back these templates or tell VS2010 to reset all templates?

A bit frustrating, I'm having to create projects on my laptop then copy them to my desktop manually :(

Answer (score 0):

No matter, I just reinstalled SL4 Tools and I've got my templates back once more.

Answer (score 0):

Blend 4 RC also confused VS2010 on my machine, causing the WPF UserControl template to disappear. I don't use the SL4 Tools, so solved the problem on my machine by placing the template from `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\WPF\1033` in `My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#\WPF`.

A better solution is also [described here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/2a964dcc-d627-426d-b0ab-72b34e43c2cd).